# Multi-modules application architecture

Tags: java, modularity

I would like to design an application with a core and multiple modules on top of the core. The core would have the responsibility to receive messages from the network, to parse the incoming messages and to distribute the messages to registered modules.

There are multiple types of messages, some modules may be interested to receive only some of the types. The modules can execute in parallel, or they can execute sequentially (e.g. when modules are interdependent with a well defined order of execution).

Also, it would be great if the modules could be deployed/undeployed even if the core is up.

It is completely new for me, I used to write modular application but with the multiple parts wired statically.

Which direction (i.e. framework, pattern...) should I take for such a design? I don't know if it's relevant to my question but I precise I'll use Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You has a very good approach at the `architecture level`. But it will be beneficial only when your application `layers/tire` will be at separate instance, so that you can shut down one `module/server` and while other part will still be running. Point is will you run the modules on separate instances?
- Secondly, I would like to suggest you to build the application core architecture using [Web-Service](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137004.html) either [REST](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html)/[SOAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/tutorials/ws-understand-web-services1/) as it will automatic achieve your thought that follows [Service Oriented Architecture (SOA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture). That will be `producer - consumer` relation and you can run on separate instance. And while deploying/undeploying you can still run the services part to support other client instances.
- Using Web service will also provide you a global information exchange system that will likely to communicate with several application views/front end.

Comment: I don't think I can use web services in my case since the incoming messages will be like SIP, DNS... Also, the core should provide high performance. I thought about using Netty. What do you mean by separate instances?